# what is the best way to add a second master in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 5 worker node and a master node in a kubernetes cluster. I want to add a new master in that cluster so that the cluster will be highly available. what could be the best approach to add a new master in a cluster?

Answer (score 7):

[This article](https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-high-availability-no-single-point-of-failure/) helped me a lot with understanding how HA cluster looks like in real life, so I recommend to check it out first.

Here is a quote from [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/) that describes creating HA cluster:

> #### Starting an HA-compatible cluster To create a new HA-compatible cluster, you must set the following flags in your kube-up script:
>
> - MULTIZONE=true - to prevent removal of master replicas kubelets from zones different than the server's default zone. Required if you
>   want to run master replicas in different zones, which is recommended.
> - ENABLE_ETCD_QUORUM_READS=true - to ensure that reads from all API servers will return the most up-to-date data. If true, reads will be
>   directed to leader etcd replica. Setting this value to true is
>   optional: reads will be more reliable but will also be slower.
>
> Optionally, you can specify a GCE zone where the first master replica
> is to be created. Set the following flag:
>
> - KUBE_GCE_ZONE=zone - zone where the first master replica will run. The following sample command sets up a HA-compatible cluster in the
>   GCE zone europe-west1-b:
>
>   $ MULTIZONE=true KUBE_GCE_ZONE=europe-west1-b  ENABLE_ETCD_QUORUM_READS=true ./cluster/kube-up.sh
>
> Note that the commands above create a cluster with one master;
> however, you can add new master replicas to the cluster with
> subsequent commands.
>
> #### Adding a new master replica After you have created an HA-compatible cluster, you can add master replicas to it. You add master replicas by
>
> using a kube-up script with the following flags:
>
> - KUBE_REPLICATE_EXISTING_MASTER=true - to create a replica of an existing master.
> - KUBE_GCE_ZONE=zone - zone where the master replica will run. Must be in the same region as other replicas’ zones.
>
> You don’t need to set the MULTIZONE or ENABLE_ETCD_QUORUM_READS flags,
> as those are inherited from when you started your HA-compatible
> cluster.
>
> The following sample command replicates the master on an existing
> HA-compatible cluster:
>
> $ KUBE_GCE_ZONE=europe-west1-c KUBE_REPLICATE_EXISTING_MASTER=true
> ./cluster/kube-up.sh

You can also find these resources useful:

- [Setup an HA kubernetes cluster on Bare Metal](https://github.com/salmanb/Kubernetes-HA-on-baremetal)
- [HA Kubernetes with Kubeadm](https://medium.com/@bambash/ha-kubernetes-cluster-via-kubeadm-b2133360b198)
- [On setting up highly available Kubernetes clusters](https://elastisys.com/2018/01/25/setting-highly-available-kubernetes-clusters/)
- [How to Setup Kubernetes Master HA on CentOS?](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-setup-kubernetes-master-ha-on-centos/)
- [Managing HA Kubernetes clusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppY9cqTvBVE) (Rancher Labs meetup video)